# Changing font size of main text and Centering title in "Pomona Linguistics LaTeX Template"

Tags: latex3, preamble

I am using Pomona Linguistics LaTeX Template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pomona-linguistics-latex-template/bvdxdtpwysnd) provided at Overleaf and would like to:

**(1) Change the font size of the main text and abstract**

I tried by changing from `\documentclass{article}` to `\documentclass[16pt]{article}`, but it does not change the font size. Since the font size of the abstract looks smaller, I want to change this part as well.

**(2) Center two-line title**

I want to center the title that is splitted into two lines and tried in several ways such as below. However, only the 1st line was centered and the 2nd line not.

```
\title{\centering {Hoge Hoge 1st line: \\ \centering Hoge Hoge 2nd line}}
```

I would really appreciate any support regarding these. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! If the answer meets your requirement, please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** after follow up question.

(1) You can increase the default font size of the article class **up to 12pt** using `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`. (`\documentclass[16pt]{article}` doesn't work).

For a larger main font size, you can use the package `fontsize`. For example, to have a normal font size of 16 points, you can use `\usepackage[fontsize=16]{fontsize}`

Inside the document you can insert `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, etc  for a local change. For example

```
\begin{abstract}    
\Large  Here is where you write the abstract of the paper.  
\end{abstract}
```

(2) To redefine the command `\title` add after `\input{PomonaLgcsFormatting}`

```
\makeatletter         
\def\@maketitle{% custom maketitle <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \noindent \begin{center} \Huge \bfseries \color{black} \@title\end{center}\smallskip \hrule \noindent \@author \\ \@date  
}
\makeatother
```

[image: f]

Compile with xelatex.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\input{PomonaLgcsFormatting}

%*******************************************  added 
\makeatletter         
\def\@maketitle{% custom maketitle <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \noindent \begin{center} \Huge \bfseries \color{black} \@title\end{center}\smallskip \hrule \noindent \@author \\ \@date  
}
\makeatother
%*******************************************
%   \usepackage[fontsize=16]{fontsize}% change the default font size to 16pt <<<<<

\title{Huge Huge long 1st line: \\  Huge Huge 2nd line} % two line title
    
\author{Your Name Here}
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}    
\Large  Here is where you write the abstract of the paper.  
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}  

Some normal size text.  

{\large Some  text with larger font size.}  

Some normal size text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a very quick and detailed answer. If you could also give me an example of increasing the font size of the main text, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Econ Latex Question You can increase the default font size using  `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` .  Inside the document you can insert `\large`, `\Large`, etc or  for a local change `{\large some text }`.  Please see the updated answer.