# Reference using BibTex (.bib) in "Pomona Linguistics LaTeX Template" does not work

Tags: bibtex, natbib, overleaf

This is my additional question to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669277/changing-font-size-of-main-text-and-centering-title-in-pomona-linguistics-latex?noredirect=1#comment1663651_669277). I am using "[Pomona Linguistics LaTeX Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pomona-linguistics-latex-template/bvdxdtpwysnd)" on Overleaf.

Now I am trying to use BibTex to cite papers and have them in Reference by adding `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` in my preamble and `\bibliography{reference}` (`reference.bib` is my .bib file) in the Reference section. In addition, I tried various similar ways and spent 5-6 hours to figure out. However, the reference system did not work in this template with what I did.

I am writing a short paper in economics, and the ideal reference style looks like:

- "AuthorA and Author B (2022)" and "(AuthorA and Author B, 2022)" in the main text, and
- "AuthorA and Author B (2022). Hoge Hoge Title. Journal Nama, xxx(x):xxx-xxx." in Reference section.

I have many experiences using BibTex in my local LaTex but it is my first time using Overleaf. If you could suggest ways how to add references in "Pomona Linguistics LaTeX Template", that would be massive help.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Without showing us code and what you mean by "it's not working"  (do you get an error or not the output you want or something else?) it's hard to help you. The Pomona template loads `natbib` so you shouldn't load yourself, but simply provide an appropriate `\bibliographystyle` command. Unless you're doing linguistics, I really don't recommend using this template, however, since it loads a lot of packages you won't need.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that your `.bib` file uses underscores in citation keys. If this is the case, try adding `\noautomath` to your document preamble after inputting the Pomona code. But I really don't think you should use this code if you're not doing linguistics. If you just like the format of the document use that part of the code and comment out all the packages and code you don't need.